# Spark/Scala any working difference between groupBy function of Rdd and DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have checked and a bit curious to know the groupBy function of RDD and DataFrame. Is there is any performance difference or something else?
Please suggest.

Comment: @user9613318 how this is duplicate that post is totally different context never talk about RDD.

Answer (score -1):

Come to think of a difference between a `DataFrame.groupBy` and an `RDD.groupBy`, RDD's groupBy variant doesn't preserve the order unlike the DataFrame's groupBy variant.

```
df.orderBy($"date").groupBy($"id").agg(first($"date") as "start_date")
```

The above works as expected i.e. the aggregated results will be ordered by `date`. Since the name sounds the same for both RDD and DataFrame, one might think it will work as expected in RDD as well but nope, it's not the case. The reason is the implementation of RDD's groupBy and DataFrame's groupBy is very different. RDD's `groupBy` may shuffle data according to the keys.

Comment: I think it is misleading. `ORDER BY` will affect the execution plan, but there is no [explicit guarantee](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16207) and I am not familiar with any test suite that would cover that behavior. Quoting Sean Owen "The problem is I think just about every method doesn't necessarily preserve order, or is not intended to guarantee it, even if it might in many cases.".  My own experience shows that this behavior is not stable (or was buggy in different versions). Do you have any authoritative (JIRA, source, design docs, test) reference that supports that claim?

Comment: And "DataFrame's groupBy is very different. RDD's groupBy may shuffle data according to the keys." - this is incorrect. Both `Dataset` and `RDD` will shuffle the data. Just read the execution plan.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for that JIRA.. I don't have a supporting doc or any other resource. It was more of a thing that I had experienced in multiple cases. Sean Owen's response does throw some light in it. @Prashant, please remove the "answer" tick from this one.